# What's the [star] tag for?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I noticed that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29253309/4200092) was tagged with [star](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/star). This tag has [no summary or wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/star/info) and isn't a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/star/synonyms) for anything else.

Is there much point to keeping this tag around? We already have [a-star](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a-star) for the path-finding algorithm, and I can't think of any other relevant uses for the word "star" other than the [network topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_network) of that name.

I'd suggest that [if it weighs as much as a duck, then it's made of wood](http://whomovedmyholyhandgrenade.com/Pages/5%20Shes%20a%20witch.html), and therefore should be burninated. If there *is* a valid use for it, then the tag summary/wiki need to be updated to indicate what it is supposed to be used for.

Comment: Skimming through the question titles, it appears to be mostly about the `*` character. *sigh* :(

Comment: Or the star shape in graphics

Comment: @BilltheLizard: looking at the [earliest question with the tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262450/why-is-using-to-build-a-view-bad), I think that could well be what it was created for =)

Comment: Haha, just came here to post a burninate request for the [star] tag as well after somebody probably edited the tag wiki in response to this post.

Comment: While going through these questions, I'm running into a lot of questions about displaying text-based graphics (often using the `*` character!). There's enough of these that I feel a tag might be helpful (particularly for finding duplicates); is there one? If not, how does "console-graphics" sound?

Comment: @duskwuff: Try [ascii-art]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You know, normally Troggy would make an appearance here, but ... ***I can't even hear him over the sound of my freaking death star!***

[image]

```
[star] removed from (77 post, 86 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 77 posts modified, 86 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
```

... with no additional (tag) cleanup needed. A cursory check prior to energizing the beam showed that there's no use in asking folks to finish a manual cleanup.

Comment: Our [cruise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cruise)rs can't repel firepower of that magnitude!

Answer (score 7):

It could mean a `*` character, which has countless meanings across different languages and environments.

It could be a star shape (☆).

It could be a rating or scoring system which rates things in stars.

It could be [a type of database schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).

It could be [the EFTPOS network](http://www.star.com/).

It could be [an early graphical system from Xerox](http://www.digibarn.com/collections/systems/xerox-8010/). (Mind you, I'm not sure why anyone would still be developing software for that, but you never know.)

Heck, it could even be one of those things up in the sky.

But one thing is for clear: it doesn't have any single unambiguous meaning. I've already removed it from a bunch of the questions under the tag, and none of the questions remaining under the tag appear to be improved by it. Let's get rid of it.

Answer (score -14):

It's obviously useless.

No need to ask on meta — simply edit it out.

Comment: The tag has 114 questions, so it is better to ask on meta before doing a mass edit.