# Should we burninate the [stars] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

### Do NOT burninate this tag right now - this is a discussion, NOT an invitation to burninate this.

*If anyone ignores the rules and burninates this anyways, the mods may have to get involved with that, despite the small number of questions. So please follow the rules. Thanks!*

I don't think the [stars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stars) tag is a good tag. [The [star] tag (singular) was already burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288680/whats-the-star-tag-for). [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230515212820/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stars) is a Wayback Machine save of questions with the [stars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stars) tag.

Reading through the [burnination rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination), sadly, we are not allowed to "ad hoc" do it as nobody AFAIK has a bronze badge in that tag or a closely related one. So we have to go through the official process.

---

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

This tag is very ambiguous, and totally fails to describe the questions.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Likely no... but I suppose if it refers to the `*` character, *possibly*.

> Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?

No

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Nope. See

- [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)
- [Dereferencing a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean-in-c-c)
- Something about the `*` character
- Unicode star characters

---

As such, I *propose* that this tag gets burninated. Thoughts?

Comment: A Unicode star character is U+2217 ([ASTERISK OPERATOR](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8704&number=128)). It was the culprit in [at least two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622120/gcc-compilation-errors-related-to-while-statement) [Stack Overflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc/38500803#38500803) (`error: stray ‘\227’ in program`).

Answer (score 8):

Out of the six questions currently tagged [stars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stars), the tag refers to the [the *stars* R package](https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/index.html) in four of them ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74048891/2751851), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75249639/2751851), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76126657/2751851), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75043883/2751851)), and to miscellaneous incidental things in two others ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74430144/2751851), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75788054/2751851)). That being so, it seems reasonable to replace the tag with [r-stars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-stars) in the questions about the R package and remove it from other two.